# Simple points of an algebraic variety from an analytic point of view

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I am a specialist in fuctional analysis, but from time to time I have to use some results from algebraic geometry, and every time I face great difficulties in translating them into the language familiar to me. Can anybody help me? At the moment I need to make sure that I correctly understand the notion of *simple point* in algebraic geometry.

Let $M$ be an affine (real) algebraic variety in $\mathbb R^n$. For a given point  $x\in M$ are the following three conditions equivalent?

- $x$ is a *simple point* in $M$,
- for some neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ the intersection $U\cap M$ is a usual smooth manifold in $\mathbb R^n$,
- among all polynomials on $\mathbb R^n$ vanishing on $M$ there is a system $f_1,...,f_k$ such that the differentials $d f_1(x),...,d f_k(x)$ are linearly independent, and on some neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ the set of common zeroes of $f_1,...,f_k$  coincides with $V\cap M$.

I would be grateful for the references.

Comment: Just curious: where in functional analysis does one use algebraic geometry? Anyway, that's good news :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I am translating now one of my papers into English, you can look (but it is still in Russian):  http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2424 . You can also take a look at my earlier papers, which are already translated: http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3205

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, дорогой Сергей.

Comment: Как много на свете культурных, интеллигентных людей! :) Excusez-moi, je n'ai pas compris: http://math.unice.fr/laboratoire/fiche&id=201, - cela veut dire que vous parlez français? :)

Comment: Cher Sergey, ma langue maternelle est en effet le français, mais j'aime beaucoup apprendre des langues étrangères. J'étudie sporadiquement votre belle langue russe, mais  je la trouve fort difficile (en particulier son lexique) et ne la connais, hélas, que bien trop peu. En tout cas votre compliment, même peu mérité, me fait bien plaisir :-)

Comment: En fait, le français est difficile aussi (pour les étrangers). On ne peut jamais être sûr que ce qu'on dit est correct. :)

Comment: Georges, je dois traduire cet article, mais j'ai decouvert cet obstacle dedant. J'ai passé beaucoup de temps pour comprendre ça, mais sans success. Je pense que c'est la "différence culturelle" entre les matematiciens: mes "amis algébriques" ne comprendent pas mon probléme, et moi, je ne comprens pas pourquoi il n'est pas clair pour eux. Pourriez-vous m'aider? Il serais suffisant pour moi si la première condition implique (impliquerait?) la troisième. Est-ce que c'est vrai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the equivalence is not true.
For example the algebraic plane curve $C$ defined by the polynomial equation $y^3+2x^2y-x^4=0$ has the origin $O=(0,0)$ as a singularity (=non simple point).
Nevertheless its underlying set is a real-analytic submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$, and thus *a fortiori* a differential submanifold.
Milnor proves this on pages 12-13 of his book [Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Singular_Points_of_Complex_Hypersurfaces.html?id=cuAAFbBYlSsC&redir_esc=y).

My different proof, as an algebraic geometer, is rather to remark that $C$ is a rational curve and to parametrize it by the usual trick of writing $y=tx$.
Hence I consider  the differentiable map $$ \mathbb R\to C:t\mapsto (t^3+2t,t^4+2t^2) $$  .
Since that map is  a proper  bijective immersion, its image $C$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Georges, if we remove the second condition, will the remaining ones (the first and the third) be equivalent?

Comment: And does the first condition at least imply the second and the third?

Comment: Dear Sergei, yes the first and third conditions are equivalent, and the third implies the second by the usual implicit function theorem. A reference is Bochnak-Coste-Roy's book (en français!) [Géométrie algébrique réelle](https://books.google.fr/books?id=9CuwNR3hHHEC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=bochnak+coste+roy&source=bl&ots=NmhVI84LFS&sig=uLW_gwblFUCLhJul_dTrKtd0c0k&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=aJZpVb-vH8GgUuPSgKgM&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=bochnak%20coste%20roy&f=false), Proposition 3.3.9, page 61.

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you, Georges!!!!!!!!

Comment: С удовольствием, дорогой Сергей.

Comment: The book can be downloaded  [here](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=C023BF46E5D4D36DC326338149B8D23E).

Comment: Merci! Georges, if this does not frighten you, I'll add you to the list of acknowlegements: you'll be there together with E.B.Vinberg, V.L.Popov, and P.I.Katsylo (i.e. with those who treat questions like this as idiotic). :)

Comment: I'll certainly be flattered to be in such excellent company.  Whether I deserve it is a different question, which I'd rather not discuss :-)

Comment: Georges, I eventually posted this paper in arxiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2424v4 I  thanked you and other people (on page 7). What we discussed here is mentioned there on pages 27-28. Thank you!  :)

Comment: Dear Sergei, thanks a lot. This looks like a  quite interesting article.